# Accessing struct variable gives error as "Cant locate object method"

Tags: perl, struct

I have a struct as follows.

Struct that contains array of Include paths, and cpp file name which is getting compiled.

```
struct( SourceFile_compile_line => [
    include_path_list => '@', # include path list
    source_filename => '$', # CPP file name
    include_list_index => '$', # no of include path list.
    object_file => '$',
]);
```

I have assigned a source file name path as below, where `$a_path` contains fullpath of .cpp file.

```
$compile_line_array->source_filename($a_path);
```

In one function, I will give this struct variable as arugment,

```
get_list_of_headers($compile_line_array);
```

and access that variable in the function as follows.

```
sub get_list_of_headers{
    my $compile_line_array;
    $compile_line_array = SourceFile_compile_line->new();
    $compile_line_array = $_;
```

following line in function `get_list_of_headers()` gives error;

```
print $compile_line_array->source_filename;
```

error is:

```
Can"t locate object method "source_filename".
```

Comment: This presumably is code that goes with some module. You should mention *which* modules. A "struct" is not a Perl data structure.

Comment: Assuming you are using Class::Struct but what is the line `$compile_line_array = $_` for? that appears to be your problem since $_ has no meaning in this context.

Comment: Hi Albe - I have called the function with argument as follows get_list_of_headers($compile_line_array);, i have edited the original question

Comment: Hi TLP: can you please eloborate your answer. Does "source_filename" resembles some perl builtin package name or method

Comment: But with that line you threw away your object, regardless of what your arguments were. Are you trying to use @_? @TLP is just pointing out that you should mention Class::Struct prominently, otherwise struct seems to come out of the blue.

Comment: @user3392184 Nope. Do you not know how to check which modules your code is using? It is the lines (usually at the top) which start with `use` or `require`, such as `use Foo::Bar qw(foo bar baz);`

Comment: I used @_, i get following error Can't call method "source_filename" without a package or object reference at D:\Kotrappa\FOSS\ScriptDevelopment\ParseDetailedLogFile.pl line 231

Comment: Maybe I am confusing things. Are you `use`ing Class::Struct? (going back to @TLP's excellent point)

Comment: @TLP - I use following modules use strict;
use File::Find ();
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use Class::Struct;
use Data::Dumper;

Comment: Please provide a minimal *runnable* demonstration of the problem.

Comment: Shall I paste complete code?

Comment: I get error when I paste 270 lines of code

Comment: So this is related to `Class::Struct`, although it seems your problem might be unrelated to the module. You did not use `@_`, you used `$_`, which is a completely different variable.

Comment: I used @_, but I got error"Cant call method "source_filename", hence I removed calling function with struct arugment, and accessing struct by declaring it globally. this sloved problem, but why cant we pass struct variable as argument to function

Comment: If it is a Perl data structure, you can pass it. Why don't you show the code where you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line:

```
$compile_line_array = SourceFile_compile_line->new();
```

to:

```
$compile_line_array = SourceFile_compile_line->new(
  include_path_list => shift, # include path list
  source_filename => shift, # CPP file name
  include_list_index => shift, # no of include path list.
  object_file => shift
);
```

assuming you are passing your arguments in that order and the first thing passed is an array reference. If the include_path is an array you need to put it at the end of the argument list.

Here you would call it thus:

```
get_list_of_headers( \@include_path, $source_file, $include_list_index, $object_file );
```

Comment: This means that we can not pass struct as a argument in perl?

Comment: this worked, but I have variable array, hence I have index which keeps track of array count. Is there way to reference structure via pointer like syntax in perl

Comment: Okay I see what you are trying to do but it gets kind of complicated. I will edit.